# Web requests work fine for 10 seconds after bootup, but few minutes after that some don't respond

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, internet-connection

Within those few minutes, I can ping some websites but not others. Discord works fine. Anything in the browser just keeps on loading.

Every thing is fine after those few minutes, though.

I'm using a Netis WF2190 USB wireless adapter on a PC running Windows 10. I have updated the drivers, but still the same issue.

This also all happens when I get my PC out of sleep.

Any advice?

Comment: How can you be disconnected if you can ping some websites and at least one internet app is working? Perhaps you should describe the problem in more detail.

Comment: I'll change the title then. The toolbar says I still have internet connection during these moments. It's more like some web requests don't succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Easy question to ask, but not easy to sort out.

Ping is one of your friends.  Learn how to use it effectively.  It bypasses lots of stuff and tests the IP layer at a lower level.  You can set it up to continuously report if you have a connection to your router, or beyond to some other server.

Start by seeing if you have a good connection to your router.  This tries to break your problems in half, excluding issues, with your browser, TCP layer, ISP and their cable modem or whatever.

Then if you have good basic 'link layer' connectivity, move up the ladder and test for a trace-route, or move down and connect to the network with a cable rather than wi-fi.